# Locus of center of a circle

Tags: geometry

The ends A and B of a fixed line of length a and the ends C and D of another line of length b slide upon the axes with one end on X axis and the other on y axis.How to find locus of center of circle passing through A B C and D? Please some help
A hint maybe

Comment: Have you drawn any pictures? What have you tried? Why should those four points lie on a circle?

Comment: We have to find locus of the circle

Comment: There is a unique circle through $A$, $B$ and $C$. The fourth point $D$ need not be on that circle. If you want an answer to your question rather than downvotes you will have to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to, given the lengths of the segments $a$ and $b$, find an arrangement where a circle passes through all four points, here's the basic picture:

[image]

The perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$ (dashed dark lines) are the points equidistant from $A,B$ and $C,D$ respectively. They will intersect at a candidate center for the circle.

But the bisectors for $AC$ and $BD$ (green dashed lines) must also intersect at the supposed center, which is not the case above.

So the problem is whether in the general case by some arrangement of the fixed-length segments the two intersections can be made to coincide. I'd guess yes. Since there are just two independent variables, seems like there are enough equations to find out.

Comment: +1 I think you have correctly figured out the badly asked question: the OP is looking for the positions of the line segments that do in fact make the four endpoints cocircular.

Comment: There's a trivial case where the segments are parallel at 45 degrees to the axes (and their bisectors co-linear), but I think there may be another solution too.

Comment: You can reverse engineer the problem by starting with a circle that intersects each axis twice and finding the chords. I wonder if we're helping the OP ...